# C++ primer exercise 1.19, first attempt at the "if" statement

Tags: c++, visual-c++

In an earlier exercise i wrote a program that took two inputs and printed out the numbers between the two numbers. in exercise 1.19, i am asked to rewrite the program so that it can handle the issue of the first number being smaller than the second number. i am asking 2 questions:

1. i feel as though i played a dirty trick with the if statement that
   just switches the numbers around in the correct order. is that bad
   coding?
2. what i wrote works, it "handles" the issue of the user inputting a
   number that is smaller than the second. however since i am very new to
   programming and only in chapter 1 of C++ primer. am i missing
   something important here that would cause me to write the code
   "better" (EX: if i understood X concept then i would wrote the "if"
   statement better/differently)

```
int main()
{
    int v1 = 0, v2 = 0, e1 = 0, e2 = 0, sum = 0;

    std::cout << "Input first integer: ";
    std::cin >> v1; std::cout << std::endl;
    e1 = v1;

    std::cout << "Input secound integer: ";
    std::cin >> v2; std::cout << std:: endl;

    if (v1 > v2)
    {
        e1 = v1;
        e2 = v2;
        v1 = e2;
        v2 = e1;
        e1 = v1;    
    }
    while (v1 <= v2)
    {
        sum += v1;
        ++v1;
    }
    std::cout << "The inclusive sum of " << e1 << " and " << v2 << " is "
        << sum;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You seem to have a couple extra, superfluous `e1 = v1` statements:  One just after `std::cin >> v1; ...` and one at the very end of the "then" clause of `if (v1 > v2)`.  Otherwise, the only thing that you might "improve" is how you swap `v1` and `v2`.  The traditional way is with just one extra variable ( `tmp = v1; v1 = v2; v2 = tmp`) and the modern C++ way is to use `std::swap()`.  You look pretty well on track overall.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your second question (and indirectly your first) I recommend that you use the `swap` function from the C++ Standard Library. You can check it out [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/swap/). In general, using STL code is better than writing functions yourself (for obvious reasons).

So to implement it in your code, you'll need to first:

```
#include <algorithm>
```

Then in the body of that first if statement, just say:

```
std::swap(v1, v2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use only a single extra variable, and simplify your `if` considerably.

```
int v1 = 0, v2 = 0, sum = 0;

std::cout << "Input first integer: ";
std::cin >> v1; std::cout << std::endl;

std::cout << "Input secound integer: ";
std::cin >> v2; std::cout << std:: endl;

if (v1 > v2)
{
   int tmp = v1;    // Store v1 in a temp variable
   v1 = v2;         // Move v2's value into v1
   v2 = tmp;        // Move temp variable into v2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I did for this is used an `if else`

```
int main() 
{
    int val1 = 0, val2 = 0, sum = 0;
    std::cout << "Enter in 2 numbers " << std::endl;

    std::cin >> val1;
    std::cin >> val2;

    // if the first value is smaller than the second then do below

    if(val1<val2)
    {

        sum = val1; // setting sum equal to the first value entered


        while(val1<=val2) // run while val1 is less than or equal to val2
        {
            std::cout << sum << std::endl; // printing sum
            sum++; // adding +1 to sum
            val1++; // adding +1 to val1 otherwise it will print sum to infinity
        }
    }
    else // If the second value is smaller than the first entered do below
    {

        sum = val2; // setting sum equal to the second value entered

        while(val2<=val1)
        {
           std::cout << sum << std::endl;
            sum++;  // adding +1 to sum
            val2++; // adding +1 to val2 otherwise it will print sum to infinity
        }
    }

    std::cout << "woot!" << std::endl;
    return 0;

}
```

It gets rid of the swapping. Took me a little while to get it. I didn't think I needed to add the `val1++` or `val2++` so it was just printing out numbers as fast as possible. Cool to look at, but not what I wanted. Hope this helps somebody!

Note: Mine is a little different from what the problem is asking for. Adding a set of numbers together but I believe the same logic can be used.

Comment: While your solution looks like it would work it results in a lot of duplicated code.  Swapping is a better solution, or wrapping the logic in a function and then calling it with the parameters in the proper order.